# Hikari Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: java, hikaricp

We have Spring-boot/Hibernate/MYSQL application in our project and use Hikari as the connection pool. After a few minutes when our service is started we found the following problem:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

**our config of datasource as follow:**

---

spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=36000

spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=2

spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000

spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=60000

spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=3000

spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=240000

any one here can give me some clue, Thank you!

Comment: Please check this URL https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you tell us at least, which versions are you using?

Comment: HikariCP-3.2.0 Mysql 6.0.6 Spring boot 1.5.3.RELEASE Hibernate 5.0.9.Final

Answer (score 12):

You probably have transactions open that you never closed. As time goes by these transactions keep piling up and no new connections can be opened. The connection timeout hits and you get this unable to acquire JDBC connection.

You need to check all your transactional methods and make sure you close/commit them as soon as you are done

I would like to add a specific scenario where we had these issues. This involved a method annotated with @Transactional 
Database connections open within this method would be inside on open transaction until this method exits. The issue with our program was this was making few HTTP calls and the transactions would be open until the HTTP calls were done. As more calls to this service method were piling up more transactions were in open state than being closed.

Moral of the story: Open transactions, do your stuff quickly and then close the transaction; either implicitly by exiting methods marked @Transactional or by explicit call to transaction close.

Comment: Do you know how to see open transactions at DB level or maybe even Spring Boot level?

Comment: You can use grafana and mysql monitor to check the open connections. We have it setup for spring boot

Comment: @GaneshKrishnan : how to do same using grafana?

Comment: @prab2112 do the same what? can you please clarify what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: as u mentioned you used grafana , mysql monitor setup , how did you excatly did it? @GaneshKrishnan